# Calling methods from Android ViewModel in background

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I was having some problem when trying to implement Android Architecture Component with Async Task. Here is the sequence, I select a button in screen A, it will execute async task A to display dialog fragment with a button, then I select the button in dialog fragment, it will execute async task B. In the sasync task B doInBackground(), I will call restart() from ViewModel.

When the very first button onClick in screen A:

```
upgradeTask = new UpgradeTask(this);
upgradeTask.execute((Void) null);
```

When the button in dialog fragment onClick in async task A:

```
private final Context mContext;
public RunUpgradeTask(final Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

runUpgradeTask = new RunUpgradeTask(mContext);
runUpgradeTask.execute((Void) null);
```

In the async task B, I will execute a method in viewModel:

```
RunUpgradeViewModel runUpgradeViewModel = 
ViewModelProviders.of(mContext).get(RunUpgradeViewModel.class);
runUpgradeViewModel.restart();
```

Then, inside my viewModel, I have this method:

```
 public void restart(){
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("REBOOT", "Could not reboot", ex);
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, in my async task B where I call the method in viewModel which is this part:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(mContext)
```

It told me **"cannot resolve android.content.Context"** error message and it highlighted at mContext variable. The mContext variable is the context I passed from the very first screen A. Any ideas how to resolve this? Or am I doing it correctly as I spent my past few days trying to understand Android Architecture Component but I not sure if I understand them correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the exact stack trace for your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no stack trace as I was unable to compile it due to that error. Let me highlight the error message in the question :)

Comment: @Onheiron Hmm any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Pass activity reference to mContext and make sure your activity implemented lifecycle.